# No module named pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, ubuntu, pyodbc

I have a script in VM instance (Ubuntu) that I want to run, however, I am getting an error of

```
"ImportError: No module named pyodbc"
```

I have tried to download drivers from the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#microsoft-odbc-driver-17-for-sql-server

Then installing the package. But still, an error is remaining. Any helps?

Thanks :)

Comment: The drivers you want are found here: [Python SQL Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: How did you install them? Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: Try `pip3 install --user pyodbc`